# Sample example to implement TripAdvisor api - iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, ios4

I have tried a lot for finding some example to implement TripAdvisor api. But I didn't get any demo code for implementing it in my iOS application.

I don't know any starting point to implement it.

so please help me and suggest if you know any good demo.

Comment: No I didn't get any update for this.

Comment: Alright, thanks for hitting back :)

Answer (score -1):

TripAdvisor API is in [JSON format](https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/documentation/location/), you can parse it using [Restkit](http://restkit.org/) for example.

Comment: is there any apii which provide tripadviser review in xml or json format.

Comment: Your answer is invalid and doesn't help in anyway to the question asked. Please review.

Comment: @cookiemonsta back then, Tripadvisor had an XML API ([now it is a JSON one](https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/documentation/location/)). And you can use Restkit to interact with it. May I ask what your concern is?

Comment: My concern is that I want users to select a restaurant of choice nearby, rate them and write a review about them and then submit it on TripAdvisors, how can I do that with that API? Now that API that you provided does that for me, but not the one before it.